# How to debug Web3JS for a not yet deployed contract?

Tags: remix, contract-debugging, javascript, browsers, javascript-vm

I have remix-ide installed.

I want to debug how my contract can be interacted in a browser using Web3JS.

How can I can run it in browser? Can it be done with JavaScript VM? Or which VM I should install? how to run it?

Do I need to install any browser plugins in order to do debugging? If yes, which plugins to install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To interact with a contract it is mandatory to deploy it. You can't run the smart-contract directly into the browser as it is stored and executed in the EVM.

You don't need a JavaScript VM then, you just need an Ethereum VM, for which you'll find some written in JavaScript like [Ethereumjs-vm](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-vm).

If you need a whole emulated network you can try to use [Ganache-cli](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli).

You'll have then to deploy your smart contract on your test network. To test interactions easily you can use [Metamask browser plug-in](https://metamask.io/) so you can interact with the networks with only a few clicks.